# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in NGINX with shiny server not working

Tags: nginx, https, shiny-server

Here I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial to set up a shiny server and redirect http to https via nginx.

I set my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` with the configurations below. I manage to access the shiny app *myapp* through *https://example.com*. This means nginx is correctly routing  *https://example.com* to *http://example.com:3838/myapp*.

The problem is that when I visit *http://example.com* nginx does not redirect me to *https://example.com* as it should.

Any ideas why this it happening?

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://my_server_ip:3838/myapp;
       proxy_redirect http://my_server_ip:3838/myapp/ https://$host/;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_read_timeout 20d;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the error is here. On the one hand you should enter the address of the app, e.g. 127.0.0.1 and on the other hand you want to forward to the folder /myapp/. But this works different with Nginx. [link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

    location /myapp/ {
....
    }

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved this by removing the suffix `/myapp` from `proxy_pass` and `proxy_redirect`. Still I am quite surprised that nginx is redirecting to the right app, since there are several apps available in this shiny server and I don't define which I want anywhere in the config file. It's a bit like magic and I don't like it...

Comment: Super I put it in again as an answer so that the next one can see it as well.

Comment: Its not magic Nginx routes to port 3838. You can set it with location parts like "location /myapp { ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is here. On the one hand you should enter the address of the app, e.g. 127.0.0.1 and on the other hand you want to forward to the folder /myapp/. But this works different with Nginx.

Remove: /myapp from proxy_pass and proxy_redirect

[Link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)